# Create an AMI with EC2 Launch V2 and make userdata run again after reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I'm creating an AMI using Packer, this AMI has EC2 Launch V2 to install in the instance. I want to create instances from this AMI and make sure that the userdata of the instance can run again after I restart the instance. So here is the agent-config.yml file :

```
version: 1.0
config:
- stage: boot
  tasks:
  - task: extendRootPartition
- stage: preReady
  tasks:
  - task: activateWindows
    inputs:
      activation:
        type: amazon
  - task: setDnsSuffix
    inputs:
      suffixes:
      - $REGION.ec2-utilities.amazonaws.com
  - task: setAdminAccount
    inputs:
      password:
        type: random
  - task: initializeVolume
    inputs:
      initialize: all
  - task: executeScript
    inputs:
    - frequency: always
      type: powershell
      runAs: localSystem
      content: |-
        'C:\tools\UserData.ps1'
  - task: setWallpaper
    inputs:
      path: C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2Launch\wallpaper\Ec2Wallpaper.jpg
      attributes:
      - hostName
      - instanceId
      - privateIpAddress
      - publicIpAddress
      - instanceSize
      - availabilityZone
      - architecture
      - memory
      - network
- stage: postReady
  tasks:
  - task: startSsm
```

The task that does that for me here is : executeScript and you notice that this task calls a ps1 file : `'C:\tools\UserData.ps1'`. Why don't I just call directly the original userdata file from EC2 Launch V2 directory ? Well because this directory is named randomly and it changes at everytime : ( see the random numbers at the end )

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\EC2Launch075546250
```

So I made this script that I call when I create the AMI :

```
write-output "Retreiving the User data script ..."
$instanceId=(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id')
$UserData_encoded = (Get-EC2InstanceAttribute -InstanceId $instanceId -Attribute userData).UserData 
$content = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($UserData_encoded))
Set-Content C:\tools\Userdata.ps1 $content
```

So now I have the userdata inside a fixed name path: `C:\tools\Userdata.ps1`

Except that this doesn't  work, because when I create an EC2 instance with this AMI, the script that gets the userdata doesn't run again and I end up with userdata to run after reboot like this:

```
PS C:\tools> type .\Userdata.ps1
<powershell>

write-output "Running User Data Script"
write-host "(host) Running User Data Script"

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine -Force -ErrorAction Ignore

# Don't set this before Set-ExecutionPolicy as it throws an error
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

# Remove HTTP listener
Remove-Item -Path WSMan:\Localhost \listener\listener* -Recurse

# WinRM
write-output "Setting up WinRM"
write-host "(host) setting up WinRM"

cmd.exe /c winrm quickconfig -q
cmd.exe /c winrm quickconfig '-transport:http'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config" '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/winrs" '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service" '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/client" '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service/auth" '@{Basic="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/client/auth" '@{Basic="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/service/auth" '@{CredSSP="true"}'
cmd.exe /c winrm set "winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP" '@{Port="5985"}'
cmd.exe /c netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote administration" new enable=yes
cmd.exe /c netsh firewall add portopening TCP 5985 "Port 5985"
cmd.exe /c net stop winrm
cmd.exe /c sc config winrm start= auto
cmd.exe /c net start winrm

</powershell>
```

What is the solution to this issue ?

Comment: Haven't used packer but faced similar problem last week and posted my approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73002259/13930970 hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it's worth, User Data should be in a separate yaml file user-data.yml.  Maybe try running it from there and see if you have any better luck?

I found your question here because I'm running into my own User Data issues.  I'm using EC2 Image Builder to create a Server 2022 image.  The problem is that after the pipeline runs and creates my image, when I use that image on my auto-scaling group the User Data never runs.  With EC2 Config you could specify that User Data runs on the next boot, but I'm having a hard time finding the secret sauce to do that here.  I may end up borrowing your User Data script to pull user data from the

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of problems here:

- Your UserData.ps1 file is not a valid PowerShell script, since it is wrapped in `<powershell>...</powershell>` XML tags, so running `powershell UserData.ps1` won't work.
- You are mixing EC2Launch `v1` with `v2`. Your UserData.ps1 is in the format of an EC2Launch `v1` userdata script. While `v2` has backwards-compatibility with `v1` and can understand this format, it's important to note that they are different versions.
- The `agent-config.yml` file (which is an EC2Launch `v2` concept) is separate from userdata. You can run custom scripts by adding them to `agent-config.yml`, but that's not the usual way to run user data scripts (which run after all the tasks in `agent-config.yml` are complete). It's better to let EC2Launch execute your user data in the proper manner, rather than adding extra config to execute it yourself.

To solve your problem, I think you have two options:

1. Add `<persist>true</persist>` to your original userdata script, and then remove your edits to `agent-config.yml` (you can just leave it as default). This will make the userdata run on each boot.
2. Use an EC2Launch `v2` userdata format instead of `v1`, which would look something like this:

   ```
   version: 1.0
   tasks:
     - task: executeScript
       inputs:
         - frequency: always
           type: powershell
           runAs: admin
           content: |-
             ... set up WinRM here ...
   ```